# Trade-offs and considerations for conditional tuple unpacking in Python: primarily performance but also stylistic considerations for maintainability

Tags: python, django

I have a piece of logic in **Python** that involves tuple unpacking based on conditions.

The code instantiates two variables, and assigns to these variables the unpacked values of a tuple.

This tuple is defined conditionally: if a conditional_expression is true, then a function executes returning a tuple, else default values are provided and assigned.

My understanding is there are two simple ways to implement this, as follows:

```py
# Method 1 #
if conditional_expression:
    processed_data, context = tuple_returner(raw_data)
else:
    processed_data, context = raw_data[0], None


# Method 2 #
processed_data, context = (
    tuple_returner(raw_data)
    if conditional_expression
    else raw_data[0], None
)
```

Now I have tried both ways, and both work well as expected.

My question is two-fold:

1. Is either method likely to be more **performant** than the other (in a standard CPython implementation)? I do not notice any substantial differences when running `timeit` tests (although method 2 seems ever so slightly slower - *see bottom snippet*), but I was wondering if anything deeper is happening under-the-hood that I'm not aware about.
2. Is either method more **Pythonic** and generally preferred by the community than the other? I couldn't see anything specific inside **PEP8** to guide me on this. Both seem readable to me but this code-base will last a long time and be worked on by several contributors, so would like to adhere to best practices.

FWIW the actual code is part of a large **Django** project, involving some complex business logic inside a Celery task, and this paradigm is repeated a lot throughout the tasks where we process data and maintain context *(and sometimes we unpack far more than just two values)*. Therefore if there are Django-specific stylistic considerations then that would be useful to know!

---

For those who want to see my `timeit` evaluation, see below:

```py
import timeit
import random

def tuple_returner(data):
    return data * 2, data * 3

def method1():
    conditional_expression = random.choice([True, False])
    raw_data = random.randint(1, 1000)
    if conditional_expression:
        processed_data, context = tuple_returner(raw_data)
    else:
        processed_data, context = raw_data, None

def method2():
    conditional_expression = random.choice([True, False])
    raw_data = random.randint(1, 1000)
    processed_data, context = tuple_returner(raw_data) if conditional_expression else (raw_data, None)

time1_a = timeit.timeit(method1, number=10000000)
time1_b = timeit.timeit(method1, number=10000000)
time1_c = timeit.timeit(method1, number=10000000)
time1_d = timeit.timeit(method1, number=10000000)
time1_e = timeit.timeit(method1, number=10000000)
time1_mean = (time1_a + time1_b + time1_c + time1_d + time1_e) / 5
time1_median = sorted([time1_a, time1_b, time1_c, time1_d, time1_e])[2]
time2_a = timeit.timeit(method2, number=10000000)
time2_b = timeit.timeit(method2, number=10000000)
time2_c = timeit.timeit(method2, number=10000000)
time2_d = timeit.timeit(method2, number=10000000)
time2_e = timeit.timeit(method2, number=10000000)
time2_mean = (time2_a + time2_b + time2_c + time2_d + time2_e) / 5
time2_median = sorted([time2_a, time2_b, time2_c, time2_d, time2_e])[2]

print("Method 1: mean = {0}, median = {1}".format(time1_mean, time1_median))
## -> Output:  Method 1: mean = 10.77958505996503, median = 10.693453999934718

print("Method 2: mean = {0}, median = {1}".format(time2_mean, time2_median))
## -> Output: Method 2: mean = 11.350917899981141, median = 11.356302100000903
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seem to distill down to:

> Is a traditional multiline `if/else` faster than the single line
> equivalent

secondly,

> is one preferred over the other.

My opinion here, but I prefer `method2()` (single line) over `method1()` as long as the intent remains clear.

Let me see if I can address the first part though by taking some noise out of the system

First, let's move the definition of `raw_data` out of the method call as it will just add noise. Let's also define a second `tuple_returner()` method and call it as that will ensure that the "work" done by both branches is identical.

Perhaps like:

```py
import timeit
import random

def tuple_returner1(data):
    return data, None

def tuple_returner2(data):
    return data, None

def method1():
    conditional_expression = random.choice([True, False])
    if conditional_expression:
        processed_data, context = tuple_returner1(raw_data)
    else:
        processed_data, context = tuple_returner2(raw_data)

def method2():
    conditional_expression = random.choice([True, False])
    processed_data, context = tuple_returner1(raw_data) if conditional_expression else tuple_returner2(raw_data)

raw_data = random.randint(1, 1000)

for _ in range(10):
    time1_a = timeit.timeit(method1, number=1_000_000)
    time2_a = timeit.timeit(method2, number=1_000_000)
    pct_2_vs_1 = round((time1_a - time2_a) / time1_a, 4)
    print(pct_2_vs_1)
```

This produces a result for me like:

```
0.0338
-0.0558
0.0527
-0.0166
0.0073
0.009
0.0198
0.0175
-0.0283
-0.0022
```

suggesting to me that there is potentially no effective difference in performance with no branch prediction in play. What if we move

```
    conditional_expression = random.choice([True, False])
```

out of the methods allowing for better possibility of branch prediction

```py
import timeit
import random

def tuple_returner1(data):
    return data, None

def tuple_returner2(data):
    return data, None

def method1():
    if conditional_expression:
        processed_data, context = tuple_returner1(raw_data)
    else:
        processed_data, context = tuple_returner2(raw_data)

def method2():
    processed_data, context = tuple_returner1(raw_data) if conditional_expression else tuple_returner2(raw_data)

raw_data = random.randint(1, 1000)
for _ in range(20):
    conditional_expression = random.choice([True, False])
    time1_a = timeit.timeit(method1, number=1_000_000)
    time2_a = timeit.timeit(method2, number=1_000_000)
    pct_2_vs_1 = round((time1_a - time2_a) / time1_a, 4)
    print(pct_2_vs_1)
```

I see results like:

```
-0.0567
-0.0068
0.0111
0.0593
0.0043
0.0991
0.0207
-0.1114
0.0159
0.0493
```

Again suggesting to me that there is little to no effective performance difference between the two strategies. For what it is worth though, you can take a look at the dissembley and see if you see anything that might suggest a difference

**Method 1:**

```
 12           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (conditional_expression)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       10 (to 20)

 13           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (tuple_returner1)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (raw_data)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (processed_data)
             14 STORE_FAST               1 (context)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE

 15     >>   20 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (tuple_returner2)
             22 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (raw_data)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             26 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (processed_data)
             30 STORE_FAST               1 (context)
             32 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

**Method 2:**

```
 18           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (conditional_expression)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        6 (to 12)
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (tuple_returner1)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (raw_data)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 JUMP_FORWARD             3 (to 18)
        >>   12 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (tuple_returner2)
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (raw_data)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
        >>   18 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             20 STORE_FAST               0 (processed_data)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (context)
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

Though the first is longer, the end result seems the same in both cases with the exception of a branch in the second that does a `JUMP_FORWARD` as an extra instruction. I guess technically making the second slower.

Comment: Thanks @JonSG, that disassembly was exactly what I was looking for. The only substantive difference seems to be the additional `JUMP_FORWARD` call in the single-line definition, which looks to be essentially a negligible overhead unless the call is made a huge number of times (e.g. in a large or nested loop). Therefore is probably best to treat as a stylistic preference.